# How to fade in a div on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery. I need a div to fade in when the page loads.

```
<div id=monster></div>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It cannot be simpler:

```
$(function(){  // $(document).ready shorthand
  $('#monster').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

If your div is not initially hidden, you could hide it before the animation:

```
 $('#monster').hide().fadeIn('slow');
```

The speed parameter can be `'slow'`, `'normal'`, `'fast'` or the number of milliseconds to run the animation.

Answer (score 5):

[jQuery/fadeIn](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeIn)

```
$(function() {
    $("#monster").fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**See working demo**

```js
$('#monster').hide().fadeIn('slow');
```

```css
#monster{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #0095ff;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=monster>
  <pre>
    This is demo text.
    This is demo text.
    This is demo text.
    This is demo text.
  </pre>
</div>
```