# JavaScript change page effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, fade

Hi by any chance anyone will know how to do the fade in fade out change page effect in JavaScript?

Like this..
**http://soulwire.co.uk/hello**

I have tried this..

But when fadeout is not linking together..I mean not smooth like the above website.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>





<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

$('body').css('display', 'none');

$('body').fadeIn(1000);



$('.link').click(function() {

event.preventDefault();

newLocation = this.href;

$('body').fadeOut(2000, newpage);

});

function newpage() {

window.location = newLocation;

}

});
</script>
```

Sorry am just think of....does background slideshow will work??? But on top can I add php/html code?

Another example...http://www.louisebradley.co.uk/portfolio/

Comment: Tried anything ? show us you css and js please

Comment: hey do you want to fade out after 2 sec.....is that what you want

Comment: Ummm...when clicking on the menu button, "HELLO , EXPERIMENTS,  STREAM ,NODES" the picture with move up, is that java script?

Comment: hi ...just wonder is it work only when click on the image?

Comment: do you want it on click or on hover...........

Answer (score 0):

Hey try the below code

See its **[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/E4EjZ/1/)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        function Close()
        { 
            $('#div1').animate({ height: 50 });
        }

        function Open()
        { 
            $('#div1').animate({ height: 100 });
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="div1" style="width:100%; height: 50px; background-color: #C0C0C0;" onmouseover="Open()" onmouseout="Close()"></div>
</body>


</html>
```

Also take a look at these stuffs

**[Fade in div on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218348/fade-in-div-on-page-load)**

**[JavaScript Fade Tutorial – Fading Elements In/Out](http://www.scriptiny.com/2011/01/javascript-fade-in-out/)**

**[How to: javascript fade in fade out text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869836/how-to-javascript-fade-in-fade-out-text)**

[**.fadeIn() Tutorial**](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)